# Why Epoxy does not generate model class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, epoxy, epoxy-modelview

I want to use Epoxy for my recyclerView with kotlin, but Epoxy Model does not generate PostModel_() class, what wrong with it?

```
@EpoxyModelClass(layout = R.layout.iteam)
abstract class PostModel : EpoxyModelWithHolder<PostModel.PostHolder>() {
  @EpoxyAttribute
  lateinit var userName: String
  @EpoxyAttribute
  lateinit var avatarIcon: Drawable
  @EpoxyAttribute
  lateinit var post: Drawable

  override fun bind(holder: PostHolder) {
    holder.avatarIcon.setImageDrawable(avatarIcon)
    holder.post.setImageDrawable(post)
    holder.name.text = userName

  }

  class PostHolder : BaseEpoxyHolder() {
    @BindView(R.id.name)
    lateinit var name: TextView
    @BindView(R.id.ic_avatar)
    lateinit var avatarIcon: ImageView
    @BindView(R.id.post)
    lateinit var post: ImageView
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`?

Comment: Yes, I have this line

Comment: how did u declare dependencies ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?  I'm also facing this same issue now.- @manwhotrycoding

Answer (score 8):

One common mistake when using Epoxy in Kotlin is mixing annotation processing engines. If you copied this from Epoxy's readme:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.airbnb.android:epoxy:3.x.y'
  // Add the annotation processor if you are using Epoxy's annotations (recommended)
  annotationProcessor 'com.airbnb.android:epoxy-processor:3.x.y'
}
```

You probably forgot to apply what they suggest for kotlin users few lines later in the same readme:

**make sure to use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`**

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly deleted the first line from my model file:

```
package com.myCustomDomain.myapp.epoxyModel
```

so the auto generated files were generated with wrong filename.